# Add functionality to zoom in/out an image in an iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image, uiscrollview, uiimageview

In iPhone App I want  add functionality to (imageview or webview or other control) zoom in/out an image with pinch gesture.

Comment: You might want to check this : http://www.iphonesdkarticles.com/2008/09/multi-touch-tutorial-3.html

Comment: you want to call other methods while zooming in or out?

Comment: @Prerak : Have you tried to google it ?

Comment: @devang no I want answer from SO

Comment: @Prerak : Then use search feature of SO.

Comment: @ Warif Akhand Rishi : no I want to just display images with zoom in or or zoom out facility

Comment: @Prerak: I have added the answer for the "facility" cum functionality of the zoom in and zoom out feature for the image view.

Comment: @Prerak : Check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[iPhone]zoom+in%2Fout+using+Pinch&submit=search I have used SO search feature...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/677006/how-to-zoom-image-in-iphone

Comment: refer this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500027/how-to-zoom-in-out-an-uiimage-object-when-user-pinches-screen

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `UIScrollView` for that.

Add a UIImageView to the `UIScrollView`and configure the UIScrollView for zooming via its propertys. Check the [UIScrollview Class Reference - Zooming and Panning Section](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006922-CH3-SW36)

Edit:
Good point by Mike: Check the `PhotoScroller`sample code by Apple, too

Comment: Also see the Apple "PhotoScroller" sample code which contains an ImageScrollView class which does this. It also handles some special cases like rotation that might interest you.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this code. I have used it in one of my apps so it works:

```
- (IBAction)handlePinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

    recognizer.view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(recognizer.view.transform, recognizer.scale, recognizer.scale);
    recognizer.scale = 1;
}
```

Also don't forget to add Pinch gesture recognizer to your imageView.

[image]

Hope this helps.